# probemon.py: error: argument -f/ --mac-info: Ignored explicit argument '-s-r-l'

Tags: python

```
import time
import datetime
import argparse
import netaddr
import sys
import logging
from scapy.all import *
from pprint import pprint
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler


NAME = 'probemon'
DESCRIPTION = "a command line tool for logging 802.11 probe request frames"

DEBUG = False

def build_packet_callback(time_fmt, logger, delimiter, mac_info, ssid, rssi):
    def packet_callback(packet):

        if not packet.haslayer(Dot11):
            return

        # we are looking for management frames with a probe subtype
        # if neither match we are done here
        if packet.type != 0 or packet.subtype != 0x04:
            return

        # list of output fields
        fields = []

        # determine preferred time format 
        log_time = str(int(time.time()))
        if time_fmt == 'iso':
            log_time = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()

        fields.append(log_time)

        # append the mac address itself
        fields.append(packet.addr2)

        # parse mac address and look up the organization from the vendor octets
        if mac_info:
            try:
                parsed_mac = netaddr.EUI(packet.addr2)
                fields.append(parsed_mac.oui.registration().org)
            except netaddr.core.NotRegisteredError, e:
                fields.append('UNKNOWN')

        # include the SSID in the probe frame
        if ssid:
            fields.append(packet.info)

        if rssi:
            rssi_val = -(256-ord(packet.notdecoded[-4:-3]))
            fields.append(str(rssi_val))

        logger.info(delimiter.join(fields))

    return packet_callback

 def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=DESCRIPTION)
    parser.add_argument('-i', '--interface', help="capture interface")
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--time', default='iso', help="output time 
format (unix, iso)")
    parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', default='probemon.log', 
help="logging output location")
    parser.add_argument('-b', '--max-bytes', default=5000000, help="maximum log size in bytes before rotating")
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--max-backups', default=99999, help="maximum number of log files to keep")
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--delimiter', default='\t', help="output field delimiter")
    parser.add_argument('-f', '--mac-info', action='store_true', help="include MAC address manufacturer")
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--ssid', action='store_true', help="include probe SSID in output")
    parser.add_argument('-r', '--rssi', action='store_true', help="include rssi in output")
    parser.add_argument('-D', '--debug', action='store_true', help="enable debug output")
    parser.add_argument('-l', '--log', action='store_true', help="enable scrolling live view of the logfile")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if not args.interface:
        print "error: capture interface not given, try --help"
        sys.exit(-1)

    DEBUG = args.debug

    # setup our rotating logger
    logger = logging.getLogger(NAME)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    handler = RotatingFileHandler(args.output, maxBytes=args.max_bytes, 
backupCount=args.max_backups)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    if args.log:
        logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))
    built_packet_cb = build_packet_callback(args.time, logger, 
        args.delimiter, args.mac_info, args.ssid, args.rssi)
    sniff(iface=args.interface, prn=built_packet_cb, store=0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I get and error "probemon.py: error: argument -f/ --mac-info: Ignored explicit argument '-s-r-l'" after running the commands "python probemon.py -i wlan1mon -t unix -o ~/WonderHowTo -f -s -r -l". Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance guys.This is a wifi probe loger program. thelink https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/log-wi-fi-probe-requests-from-smartphones-laptops-with-probemon-0176303/ is helpful to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the error message, it looks like you are not separating the arguments with spaces(even though your command looks fine here) like:

`python probemon.py -i wlan1mon -t unix -o ~/WonderHowTo -f-s-r-l`

This is where the "Ignored explicit argument" error comes from. You can try with:

`python probemon.py -i wlan1mon -t unix -o ~/WonderHowTo -fsrl`

You should also add a `default=True` for those arguments and try it out.

One last thing you could do is try to set the arguments with their extended alias:

`python probemon.py -i wlan1mon -t unix -o ~/WonderHowTo --mac-info --ssid --rssi --log`

Comment: Hi Joao, Thank you very much for your answer. It worked really well.

Comment: You are welcome @rajiv, but which one worked for you?

Comment: This python probemon.py -i wlan1mon -t unix -o ~/WonderHowTo -fsrl worked for me.

Comment: I didn't try other actually.